# Floating scrolling sidebar next to a centered relative div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to place a floating sidebar, next (left side) to my content div (auto centered). I would like to place it 790px from the top and when scrolled, it would still be on the top left side of the content div. I have found solution with javascript. But no of them is working with placing the sidebar next to a centered content (I need it dynamic, for all resolutions). All solutions I have found are changing the sidebar position to fixed (in javascript code), when scrolled (bellow 790px). But if I want it still next to my centered div, I need to use absolute position for the sidebar (even when scrolled), right? Is there any solution for this, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: plz add a jfiddle so that i can help ;D

Comment: I am first time using Fiddle, hope you can see the code. What do I need is have the sidebar placed left to the content (it should be easy), but when scrolling down, the sidebar should be still visible at the same place, left, top. http://jsfiddle.net/gQ675/

Answer (score 0):

use `fixed` - it creates the illusion of a following div - for example:

html:

```
 <div id="sidebar">
        [ sidebar content ]<br>
        [ sidebar content ]<br>
    </div>
   <div id="container">
    [content]<br>
    ....    
    </div>
```

css:

```
#sidebar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 60px;
        width: 200px;
        left: 0;
        border: 1px solid #0f0;
    }
```

heres the code - **take out the javascript stuff** and **unnest the divs** and let me know if that was acceptable :D

Comment: Can I use fixed, if the central div is differently wide, according to a resolution? How can I fix the sidebar to the exact position?

Comment: explain "diff wide" - and a fiddle would be nice too!

Comment: I have placed the link at the main comment, thank you.

Comment: Thank you Bruce, it makes sense. But sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong. In my website, the sidebar is nearly not visible when page loaded, it's 790px down, and when scrolled, bellow, I need it to stick to the top. Not still being down 790px from the top. In this example, it's 60px, but I need the same functionality. When I scroll below 60px, I need to stick the sidebar to the top left. Thank you.

Comment: And also, your solution doesn't place the sidebar right next to the content div.

Comment: Left, but next to the content. Your fixed solution is placed to the left border of the browser window. And if you would like to use left: #px then I say, I need it dynamic. I don't know how wide the center content div will be. So I can't use left: #px with fixed.

Comment: if you want it dynamic - you could change the 'left' to 'margin-left: #px' or maybe 'margin-left: #%' based on screen/content size -  i would chat with you but ur rep is 11

Comment: again, if you found this helpful +1 me, bro, i need the rep

Comment: I can't +1 with 11 rep myself, sorry :( But also, your solutions are not the way how to do it, sorry again. But thank you anyway.